# SQL display maximum 2 employees hired the latest in 2021 per department

Tags: sql, sql-server

A SQL Server database has 2 tables:

- `Department`: Id
- `Employee`: Id, Department, Employee_Name, Date_Hired

I wanted to display maximum 2 employees hired the latest in 2021 per department

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE8Mt.png)

[The output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQrg.png)

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Date_Hired IN (SELECT e.Date_Hired
                      FROM Employee e
                      WHERE YEAR(e.Date_Hired) = 2021)
ORDER BY e.Date_Hired DESC
```

But it is displaying all 3 items from department 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` ?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e,
     (SELECT id,
             Date_Hired,
             row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
      FROM Employee e
      WHERE YEAR (e.Date_Hired) = 2021) sub
WHERE rn <= 2
  and e.id = sub.id
ORDER by e.Date_Hired DESC
```

Comment: the row_number() function get position of your order and save as "rs", after you just filter by your condition "rs<=2"

Comment: If you are adding an explanation, edit it into your answer, comments get removed after time.

Answer (score -1):

If your relation had integer rank numbers
describing each employee's position within a department,
then a simple WHERE clause could easily request the top K employees.
So you are looking for the `rank` query function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

The [relationship](https://blog.jooq.org/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/) among RANK, DENSE_RANK, and ROW_NUMBER is
perhaps more subtle than your unit tests and future maintainers
would care to consider.

Comment: More suited to a comment as its just tips, not a complete solution.